# checkbox column value in radGridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, telerik

I'm working with radGridView and I'm building the data assigned to it, I mean I'm creating the columns and the rows (not assigning to datasource). After adding the data to the grid I add a checkbox column that should be used to check multi rows (same as muti-select idea but using checkboxcolumn),

so this column is not bind to any data, its value should be assigned during runtime.
When I try to retrieve this checkbox column value it turned out to be null even if it's checked, I used this method to update its value, but it didn't work out:

```
   private void radGridView1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(radGridView1.CurrentCell!=null)
                if(radGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnInfo is GridViewCheckBoxColumn)
                    radGridView1.TableElement.Update(GridUINotifyAction.DataChanged);
        }
```

What should I do to get the value of the checkbox column not on valueChanged but on another button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you are getting null value, however, in my tests the check boxes always have values if they are assigned:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        radGridView1.Columns.Add(new GridViewCheckBoxColumn() { Name = "CheckBoxCol" });
        radGridView1.Rows.Add(false);
        radGridView1.Rows.Add(true);
        radGridView1.Rows.Add(false);
        radGridView1.Rows.Add(true);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRowInfo row in radGridView1.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row.Cells["CheckBoxCol"].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please provide a small sample and information how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: currentCell is the currently selected cell? I can have more than one selected row .. that's why I used checkbox.

Comment: Thank you .. adding the column programmatically solved my problem.